# Hash deference for strings

Tags: perl

using `print Dumper` my hash looks like

```
$VAR1 = { 
  '374' => { 
    'movies' => [ 'Harry potter 1', 'Harry potter 2'...], 
    'gender' => [ 'M' ], 
    'birthdate' => [ '1973/12/13' ], ...
  }
```

When i try to access the fave movies element using

```
#infoName = 'movies';
foreach my $movie (@{$profile{$iD}{$infoName}}) {

   print $movie;
}
```

I get the output '`1979/08/29`' etc which is the birthdate field? 
Is it only accessing numerics or something? 
How can i correctly print the movies from the hash?

Comment: @mpapec i checked the value of `$infoName` and it is `movies`

Comment: @mpapec I just put the Dumper statement right before where i use the loop instead of at the start of the sub-function (where i was printing the value $infoName before from), the value was changed by a function call. That was quite dumb of me, thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code you posted and your Dumper output is not properly related. If I try out your code like this:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %profile = (
    "374" => { 
        'movies' => [ 'Harry Potter 1','Harry potter 2'],
        'gender' => [ 'M' ],
        'birthdate' => [ '1973/12/13' ],
    }
);
print Dumper(\%profile);
print "----------\n";

my $iD = 374;
my $infoName = 'movies';
foreach my $movie (@{$profile{$iD}{$infoName}}) {
   print $movie."\n"
}
```

it works perfectly and prints out:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '374' => {
                     'birthdate' => [
                                      '1973/12/13'
                                    ],
                     'movies' => [
                                   'Harry Potter 1',
                                   'Harry potter 2'
                                 ],
                     'gender' => [
                                   'M'
                                 ]
                   }
        };
----------
Harry Potter 1
Harry potter 2
```

So either your `%profile` hash is not really containing what the Dumper shows, or the code you posted does some additional stuff before it is processed by the foreach block.

If this doesn't solve your problem, I suggest posting a fully working small sample program which really demonstrates the problem.